# Development Sandbox BIM 360 API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

My company in the next couple of months would like to start developing a app for BIM 360 using the BIM 360 API.  I was asked to start to practice and learning it.  I saw on the step by step that I need to setup a development sandbox which I would like to do.  The notes say to contact the Forge Partner Development Team.  Who would that be? Autodesk's page didn't leave a link or an email.

Answer (score 1):

I must agree it's a bit confusing.  Sandbox means NFR (Not for Resale) version of license. Currently, you will need to be a member of ADN (Autodesk Developer Network) or Enterprise Priority customer to get NFR license. Your company is, maybe. Could you [check this post](https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/15/development-sandbox-for-bim-360-api/) for more detail?

Since this is pre-programming question, I will be happy to assist you if you have further question there.

Comment: Thank you Mikako,  I will talk to our digital design manager and see if we can set up a sandbox project to do some testing in the new APIs.